# Unit Testing Factories Jasmine-Sinon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, sinon

I have a factory with a getter and setter

```
.factory('myService', function() {
  var car = null;
  return {
    car: car,
    get: function get() {
      return car;
    },
    set: function set(newCar) {
      car = newCar;
    }
  };
});
```

I am writing test for it but I cannot call the `set` method and have it actually set `car` to `newCar`

```
myService.set = sinon.spy();
myService.get = sinon.spy()

it('should set car to new car', function () {
  var newCar = ['a','b','c'];
  expect(myService.car).toEqual(null); //pass

  myService.set(newCar);

  dump(myService.car); //null

  expect(myService.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newCar);//pass

  expect(myService.get).toHaveReturned(newCar);//fail

});
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more problems here.

One is that the `.car` property will always be null.

```
var car = null;
return {
  car: car,
  get: function get() {
    return car;
  },
  set: function set(newCar) {
    car = newCar;
  }
};
```

Here you initialize it with `car` which is null. There will be no reference between them. This will always be null since you never change that property on the object:

```
dump(myService.car); //null
```

You might do something like:

```
return {
  car: null,
  get: function get() {
    return this.car;
  },
  set: function set(newCar) {
    this.car = newCar;
  }
};
```

But with this you might run into some `this` context issues later. Why are you trying to expose `car` if you have a getter for it?

The other thing is that you replace the entire `get` and `set` functions with this:

```
myService.set = sinon.spy();
myService.get = sinon.spy();
```

Sinon knows nothing about your original `get` and `set`.

You should do it like this:
`sinon.spy(myService, 'set');`

So sinon can wrap your function with a spy while preserving it's original behavior. [Check Sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies)

Comment: thank you! I wasn't setting my spy's correctly, didn't realize the disconnect.